# While editing react core ui admin template routes, I get 404 in every route

Tags: reactjs, routes, path, http-status-code-404

While editing react core ui admin template routes, I get 404 in every route. Because they specified the default layout route as "*". When I give "*" to the 404 route, I go to the 404 page in all routes.

Using the Home "/" route like this,
404 page "*" like this

how can i use it?

[image]

[image]